# Does the IL knows what an INTERFACE is?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, clr, csc

For example when you introduce an static class in your source code, csc compiler turns it into a sealed abstract class (Correct me if I am wrong, please).

But how about Interface; *Does the CLR knows what an interface is?* Or compiler converts it to to some kind of type declaration?

Comment: If the compiler turned an abstract class into a sealed one, how could any class possibly derive from it to implement the abstract methods?

Comment: An abstract class is very different from a static sealed class. What made you think the compiler turned one into another? And yes, the compiler does make an interface type.

Comment: Have you tried to compile an assembly and then look with ildasm?

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad typing; edited the question

Comment: For a full description on how Types are defined in the CLI you can look at section §10 in Partition II in the [CLI standard ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> For example when you introduce an abstract class in your source code,
>   csc compiler turns it into a sealed static class (Correct me if I am
>   wrong, please).

I am correcting you.

An abstract class such as:

```
public abstract class Foo
{

}
```

looks like this in IL:

```
.class public abstract auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method family hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
    }
}
```

> But how about Interface; Does the CLR knows what an interface is?

Yes, it knows. For example:

```
public interface IFoo
{

}
```

translates into:

```
.class public interface abstract auto ansi IFoo
{
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the question; I have noticed it after the post; sorry.

Answer (score 7):

You are wrong, it's the `static class` that is converted to an equivalent `sealed abstract class`.

And interfaces are full members of .NET, with distinct metadata and behavior (e.g. multiple inheritance) different from any other kind of type.

Comment: Totally right; I have fixed the question; my bad (static class --> sealed abstract in IL)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what ILSpy shows for the following code.

C#:

```
interface A
{
    void M();
}
```

IL:

```
.class interface nested private auto ansi abstract A
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
    } // end of method A::M

} // end of class A
```

So, yes, it does know.

Answer (score 1):

This is what an interface looks like to the CLR:

```
.class public interface abstract auto ansi IDisposable
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = { bool(true) }
    .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance void Dispose() cil managed
    {
    }
}
```

IDisposable taken as an example.